# Stylized radio buttons not triggering on keyboard focus state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus, accessibility

I'm having a problem with radio input buttons that I've appended to a div through jQuery. They work fine using a mouse, but when using the keyboard tab-focus state, it doesn't activate the final result.

*NOTE:* I've restyled the radio buttons to appear as rectangles holding the label names, using both visibility: hidden the radio button and used opacity: 0 on the inputs at varying times.  was placed on the label to override the quirk of event listeners on append -- doesn't seem to work on the input.

Hopefully this is enough code to get an idea of what's happening, but if not, please let me know!

**jQuery**

```
function displayCountries = (filteredResults) => {
    $countries.append(`
          <p>Choose your country</p>
          <form class="countriesFlex"></form>
    `);

    filteredResults.forEach((result) => {
          $('.countriesFlex').append(`
              <input type="radio" id="${result.origin}" name="country" value="${result.origin}" aria-hidden="true">
              <label for="${result.origin}" aria-label="click to display item with origin of ${result.origin}" tabindex = "0"> ${result.origin}</label>
          `);
   });
};
```

**CSS**

```
label,
input,
[type=submit],
a {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    &:focus {
        border: 3px solid $accent;
        outline: none;
    }
}

.countries {
    padding: 0px 0px 75px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    .countriesFlex {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-top: 30px;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    label {
        padding: 15px 30px;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: $secondary;
        color: $primary;
        text-align: center;
    }
    input {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0px;
    }
}


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/conno/rdantc03/8/
```

Comment: a complete fiddle would be better if you can add one, at first glance there is nothing that would immediately jump out on the behaviour you are experiencing in the CSS and JS. However I do wonder why you have `aria-hidden="true"` on your inputs as I can't imagine this is usable with a screen reader (unless you have implemented something in JS)?

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie -- thanks for your patience, I'm a newbie! I've added a basic fiddle! If you complete the meat and veggie selection, and then tab to the country buttons, you'll see they not only lose the border but they also don't present the result using a keyboard.PS. I added an aria-hidden as I was already including an aria-label to click on the country and thought that the screen reader would read both? If I'm misunderstanding that, please do clarify! Still learning!

Comment: You mean to say, when shifting through elements using the tab key, you can't get them to activate?

Comment: I had no issue activating the elements using only my keyboard, please specify what your issue is.

Comment: @Capagris After you select the meat or vegetable option and click the "Next" button, 3 countries will appear. If you mouse over and click one of the countries, the result will show up. But using keyboard functionality and pressing enter, there is no result displayed. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to do with how you handle the click event.

You see when you click on a `<label>` with the mouse it will activate any related checkbox / radio `<input>`.

However as labels should not be accessible via the keyboard there is no built in logic that if you press <kbd>Space</kbd> (as you would on a radio input) that it should fire a click event.

You currently use `[name=country]` as your CSS selector that fires the click event.

This works with the mouse as when you click the label it passes the click event to the corresponding input (which has the associated click event handler attached to it) and therefore works.

However when you press <kbd>Space</kbd> while a label is selected this is not passed to the corresponding `<input>` where your handler is attached.

You could do

```
$('label').click(function() {
       var labelID = $(this).attr('for');
       $('#'+labelID).trigger('click');
});
```

As a workaround as this would effectively pass the click event through to the input (**I think (the above is untested)**, if not then you would listen for `<space>` being pressed on the label and pass that through to the related input).

To ensure correct labelling I would recommend reading https://www.a11ywithlindsey.com/blog/create-custom-keyboard-accessible-radio-buttons as it illustates how to use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` plus tips for styling custom radio buttons which you could adapt.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I just saw this -- I actually did a workaround by putting an event listener on space and enter keypress, which you mentioned and totally works, phew! But this description is really great and thorough and helps me understand what's going on in a way that I wasn't completely getting at first. Thanks so much!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :-)